# Bootstrap 4 website gets auto zoomed in mobile browser

Tags: html, mobile, media, responsive

I am working on a  website built-up using bootstrap 4. Website design is working perfect on all platform but on mobile devices the website gets auto-zoom. i need to zoom-out manually in mobile devices to see the website properly. I have tried media port commands, initial scale to 1. Still not getting a solution. Please help

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` try this one.